# Resizing a view on different resolution

Tags: android, screen-resolution

I need to resize a view so that this view remains square, like in the example.

[image]
Different screens can have a different diagonal size. I need that the view named Panel2 remains a square and I also need that panel2 fits the full remainig screen height.  How can I do?

I prefear an XML solution, but now I need only a solution. Thanks.